Unexpected difference in outcome of two queries
Why do I have different outcome list from below queries using Postgres?
Query using alias in WHERE clause:
select lower(left(first_name,1) || '.' || last_name || '@xmail.com') as email
    from customer
    where email like lower('%s%');

Without using the alias in WHERE clause:
select lower(left(first_name,1) || '.' || last_name || '@xmail.com') as email
    from customer
    where lower(left(first_name,1) || '.' || last_name || '@xmail.com') like lower('%s%');

I changed the letter 's' for others, but it never returns the same result. What am I doing wrong?

Aliases can't be used (or rather, do not exist) in the WHERE clause. The customer table must have an email column. Your first query checks LIKE LOWER('%s%') against the actual column, the second one checks it against your string concatenation.

thx Marth, still have troubles getting my head around it, if i use the alias 'email' in the order by clause it works fine. as well using the the 'correct' way, seems to be retyping code.

i figured it out (using ChatGPT...):
The WHERE clause, which is evaluated before the SELECT clause, the email alias is not recognized because the database engine processes the WHERE clause before the SELECT clause. That's why you couldn't directly reference the email alias in the WHERE clause of your original query.
The way around repeating 'query script' as follows
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT lower(left(first_name,1) || '.' || last_name || '@xmail.com') AS email
FROM customer
) AS sub
WHERE email LIKE lower('%wi%');
Thx for the helps

I created an example which shows the difference (when using ORDER BY), see: https://dbfiddle.uk/oNxnWmgk

BTW: Putting code in a comment is not very readable....

email like lower('%s%') does not make much sense. Maybe lower(email) like '%s%'

@Vsn Yes, aliases are in the scope of the ORDER BY clause, but they aren't in the scope of the WHERE clause.

It is all laid out in the  docs Select in the section starting SELECT retrieves rows from zero or more tables. The general processing of SELECT is as follows: In particular 3. and 5. .

I see multiple potential problems in your query. You should start by defining what it should do exactly.
